# Why aren't css and js files loading when SpecFlow-Selenium tests are run using vstest.console.exe from the command prompt?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, specflow, vstest.console.exe

I have some tests for a web application which were automated using SpecFlow and Selenium WebDriver. When I run the test from Visual Studio's Test Explorer, the test runs fine. I'm trying to set up a CI pipeline on Jenkins and in order to run the automated tests I'm relying on vstest.console.exe. However when I run the from the command prompt using vstest.console.exe, the application didn't appear as it should. When I checked the Console in Chrome's Developer Tools, there were a quite a lot of js and css files logged as Internal Server Error. Below is a screenshot of the console error for a few files.

[image: Chrome DevTools Console]

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: You are getting a `500 Internal Server Error` from IIS. Try going to one of those URLs to see more details of the 500 error, and add those details to your question. This is likely an IIS configuration issue.

Comment: @GregBurghardt The site loads fine when I visit it manually or when the test is run via Test Explorer in Visual Studio. This only happens if the test is run using vstest.console.exe.

Comment: So pages load file when loading them through the browser *served* by the same web server the automated tests on Jenkins uses?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Yes, it was an unusual issue. What's even more odd is that it seems to have fixed itself. When I tried running the tests the next day, I didn't get the errors anymore. Save for shutting down the machine, I didn't carry out any updates to the Windows, Chrome nor ChromeDriver.

Comment: Sounds like we can chalk this one up to "Internet Gremlins." :)

Comment: @GregBurghardt Definitely!